# Constructing an IPAddress variable using Dns.GetHostEntry

Tags: c#, dns, ip

My application is sending reports to another application (which maintains a database of reports) on the network with simple `IPv4` addresses. I can construct a valid `IPAddress` in two ways:

```
string address = "200.1.2.41"; 
IPAddress ip1 = IPAddress.Parse(address);
IPAddress ip2 = (Dns.GetHostEntry(address)).AddressList[0];
```

If `address` represents an IP that is reachable, both methods are quick (though `IPAddress.Parse` is quickest). But if `address` is not reachable (eg. the server is off or the user has entered the wrong IP in Settings) then Parse is lightning quick...but `Dns.GetHostEntry` hangs for up to 9s.

I did a parameter-by-parameter check and the final variables `ip1` and `ip2` are identical. Given that Parse is always quick, and that I'm using standard four-octet `IPv4` addresses only, is there any compelling reason to use the `Dns.GetHostEntry` method? Might I need `Dns.GetHostEntry` if I switch to `IPv6` or named hosts like `FOOD.HALL.01` in future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want get an instance of `IPAddress` for your IP address string representation, than yes, using the [DNS](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) for that purpose is absolute overkill.

All sorts of timeouts, latencies, etc. are absolute expected. At least compared to the purely local parsing and disecting of the string representation that happens in `IPAddress.Parse()`. What that does is, ask the DNS server to resolve the IP address string into a hostname "entry". From that you get the IP address back that you knew all along (albeit as `string` and not `IPAddress`).

Now, if you want to be able to "convert" host names into IP addresses in the future, then yes, you need to go via DNS.

But you could always do it in that manner (conceptually):

```
// First see if it is a valid IP address rep - fast.
IPAddress ip;
if (!IPAddress.TryParse(address, out ip)) 
{
    // See if it is a hostname - slower.
    ip = Dns.GetHostEntry(address).AddressList[0];
}
```

And yes, `IPAddress.TryParse()` (or `Parse()`) can handle IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.